# Overloaded variables in python for loops?

Tags: python, loops, variables

I came across a piece of code today that prompted me to write this little function:

```
def strangeloop(n):
   for n in range(1, n):
      print n
```

strangeloop(10) ended up printing numbers from 1 to 9. My question is, Why doesn't the loop variable conflict with the argument?

Comment: Note that overloading refers to functions, not to variables. Variables are *overwritten*. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `for` loop assigns values to its loop variable(s) just like any other assignment.  You can do your code for the same reason you can do this:

```
x = 2
x = 3
```

The later assignment just overwrites the earlier one.  In your case, the loop variable overwrites the function argument.

Note that `range(1, n)` is evaluated once, before the loop begins.  So at that time it is referring to the function argument.  Once that happens, the first loop value is assigned to `n`, and then the function argument is overwritten and no longer accessible.  The loop does not "need" the function argument once it is looping.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is that `range(1, n)` creates a range object, and when the for loop sets `n` to the values in the range, it doesn't matter that the function parameter `n` is being overwritten.

It might be less surprising that this code works fine, and it works for the same reason:

```
def strangeloop(n):
   r = range(1, n):
   for n in r:
      print n
```

The value of `n` is what is passed into the range, not the variable itself, so the range object cannot see that the variable `n` has been changed.

Answer (score 1):

Pythons `for` loops work different from c `for` loops. 
`range` does not compare the running variable to its arguments.
It returns either a list of numbers (python2) or a generator that `yield`s those numbers.

The `for` loop then assigns one element after another to the running variable.

python2:

```
>>> l = range(5)
>>> l
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

python3:

```
>>> g = range(5)
>>> g
range(0, 5)
>>> list(g)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: I suspected some such thing, but I didn't know how to articulate it well enough to search for it. Thanks.